# Are Hags Fey or Fiends?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, feywild

The MM indicates that Sea Hags and Green Hags are both fey creatures while Night Hags are considered fiends.

Can anyone clarify if this is a typo and whether they're all supposed to be the same? If so, what should they be?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From page 178 of the MM:

“Night Hags were once creatures of the Feywild,  but their foulness saw them exiled to Hades long ago, where they degenerated into fiends.”

So Night Hags are Fiends.

Comment: Does this mean that Night Hags have fey ancestry?

Comment: @tillmas, probably a philosophical discussion between the words ancestry and degenerated. To answer your question. I would say yes, as it clearly states they were exiled from the Feywild.

Comment: Thanks! I was just skimming through for fey that I might summon and didn't read through the full descriptions. So I can summon 2 out of 3 hags then.

Comment: These kinds of explanations are common, but the concept of punishing an entire type of creature to explain their change from one category to another has always seemed kind of flimsy. Surely some hags were worse than others, some deserving of worse punishments, or some not deserving of this particular punishment.

Answer (score 11):

Volo's Guide to Monsters lists the Annis Hag and the Bheur Hag as fey, implying that hags are fey in general. The Night Hag appears to be an exception.